# Working with integer values in UDPGet

Tags: c, embedded, char

I'm trying to make some communication for my PIC devices and I use UDP for it.
I may send anything to socket, when i send one char like 'R' or any other. code understands it and everything works okay, but when im trying to send integer it doesnt work.

```
static UDP_SOCKET   MySocket;
BYTE                i;
```

This works:

```
if(!UDPIsGetReady(MySocket))
            return;

    UDPGet(&i);
if(i == 'R')    SetDCPWM1(255);

UDPGet(&i);
if(i == 'G')    SetDCPWM1(155);
```

This code doesn't work:

```
UDPGet(&i);
    SetDCPWM1(255-atoi(i));
```

It compiles, it doesnt crash, it just doesnt work.
The problem is a can send and recieve letters ( chars) but i cant do the same with integers. Like i may send 'R' and i recieve it, but i cant send '1' or '20', but i really want to send an integer from 0 to 255.

Comment: What do you mean "doesn't work" ? It doesn't compile ? It crashes ? You get unexpected results ?

Comment: if `( i == 'R' )` you are sending `255` and if it is `G` you are sending `155`. There is no predictable mapping here. And hence you cannot replace all if statements with a single `SetDCPWM1(255-atoi(i))`

Comment: I cannot find the functions you mentioned in any popular thrird party library, which indicates they are your own functions.  You should post the logic of those functions for us to better understand your problem

Comment: Function:
 BOOL UDPGet(BYTE *v)

  Summary:
 Reads a byte from the currently active socket.
 
  Description:
 This function reads a single byte from the currently active UDP socket, 
 while decrementing the remaining buffer length.  UDPIsGetReady should be 
 used before calling this function to specify the currently active socket.

  Precondition:
 UDPIsGetReady() was previously called to specify the current socket.

  Parameters:
 v - The buffer to receive the data being read.

  Return Values:
   TRUE - A byte was successfully read
   FALSE - No data remained in the read buffer

Comment: It's a Microchip TCP-IP stack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the `atoi` function wants a string, and you are supplying it with a single byte. Secondly, `atoi` only accepts digits, if the value you receive is a non-digit then it would have returned zero.

I suggest you try this instead:

```
UDPGet(&i);
if (isdigit(i))
    SetDCPWM1(255 - (i - '0'));
```

The `i - '0'` converts an ASCII digit to the actual value. I added the `if` statement to make sure that the received digit really is a digit, otherwise the calculation would be wrong and may even end up negative number.

Comment: it seems to be a great idea but i think that i may only recieve one byte from UDPGet(&i); so in ASCII, integer value of 255 wouldnt be 1 byte, is it right?

Comment: @HorheGarcia `i` is a single byte, and that's what `isdigit` expects and `atoi` does not. Also, the calculation will also yield a single byte.

Comment: Would you please suggest your varient?